# Is there a secret switch to force Google Drive SDK to search folder and it's child folders?

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I'm building a Google Drive SDK application and will be utilising search within the solution.

My aim is to be able to perform a full text search on the displayed folder and it's child folders with a single call.

My initial (and naive) attempt at this has only returned results for the immediate parent identified in the query string (root in the example below)

```
"'root' in parents and fullText contains 'wire'"
```

I've had a deep dive into the api documentation and can't find anything that would perform this.

Do Google have a secret property I can pass that will enable this activity... I can't believe for a second that they would have missed such an obvious use case out!

If I can't find an suitable option I will be forced to obtain a list of folders that make up the drive and then perform a full text search across the entire drive (this will return many more results than I need) and then filter down locally on my application server to get the folder results I want. Thus reducing the API call count to 2 (1 if I cache the folder list for a while)

Thoughts anyone?

Comment: There is, but I can't tell you --> It's a secret.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pulling a list of all files and filter them locally, you could pull the list of folders (and sub-folders) you want to search in (or cache them like you suggested) and build your query to have something like `([FolderID1] in parents OR [FolderID2] in parents OR ... OR [FolderIDn] in parents) and fullText contains 'wire'`.